# The "habits" tag should be removed

Tags: discussion, tags

If this site will not contain psychology or mental-hacks, the "habits" tag should be deleted. The presence of it is misleading and conflates the scope of the site.

Comment: On a sort of side not, I also personally think skepticism should be removed as it is basically someone's view on a topic and there aren't really hacks for people's opinions...

Answer (score 7):

I agree with this completely. If a new user sees the [habits](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habits) tag, they might assume that they can ask questions about dealing with habits. Right now, no one should tag anything with [habits](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habits) or edit anything about it which might encourage people to use it even more. The one question that is tagged with [habits](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habits) right now should be deleted ASAP (we'll have to wait because it was just asked) or we can retag it, but I don't really think we have an tags that fit the questions.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I retagged [the question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/5896/15) as to remove [habits](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habits). The question should be deleted ASAP.

Comment: Is it blacklisted?

Comment: @Tim That has to be done by a community manager. Hopefully by the time a user can create new tags they will be aware that mind hacks are off topic.